# Power Automate - making a Yammer-to-Trello card Flow issue

Tags: power-automate

Hi this flow with an Condition connector (IF statement) that bascially checks to see if a Yammer post has the word "idea" then add a Trello card to the Trello column named "Ideas" else if a Yammer post has the word "issue" then add a Trello card to the Trello column named "Issues."

But none of the Dynamic content yammer variables work in that with the second if statment (if a Yammer post has the word "issue" then add a Trello card to the Trello column named "Issues.") does not get triggered at all.  But the first if statement works.  why is this?

See image of the flow:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But apparently something you said had me think and apparently there is a "Add a parallel branch" option which allowed me to make 2 separate Condition connectors (one for contains "Ideas" and one for contains "issues." This solved it exactly. Assuming it is ok in Power Automate to leave the "If no" blank this works. See image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A condition will check your criteria and will output either a true (in that case it will go to If Yes) or false (If No).

When your message contains the keywords idea or issue it will result in an expression result true (If Yes).

I would suggest to use a Switch action instead.

Comment: This ok but does not help with partial text. e.g.  if someone types "I have an idea" it goes to the default column instead of the "Ideas" column

Comment: But apparently something you said had me think and apparently there is a "Add a parallel branch" option which allowed me to make 2 separate Condition connectors (one for contains "Ideas" and one for contains "issues."  This solved it exactly.